# Application of Hirzebruch Riemann Roch

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb C$ where $X$ is the universal cover of $Y$. Assume that the fundamental group of $Y$ is finite and has order $d$. Then we want to show that $\chi (X)=d \chi(Y)$ where $\chi(\cdot)$ means Euler characteristic with respect to the sheaf of regular functions.

Any ideas here? I guess it might be an easy application, but I don't see the connection between the chern class and the Todd class of $X$ and $Y$ in order to apply the Riemann Roch.

Comment: This was [crossposted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124131/application-of-hirzebruch-riemann-roch). In the future, please wait some time before posting your question in multiple fora, and when you do, provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to see hear from you that you'd already gotten an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, sorry I'll keep that in mind.